# Mentioning people/roles inside an embed (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to create for my discord server a set-roles channel, where every role is explained.
I want my bot to say everything inside an embed, so noone would be tagged if their role is mentioned there.
Unfortuanlty I really can't find a way to mention any role or any user in a simple way, without to getting the roles id and fetching the role. I have a lot of roles on my server and I just want a simple way of writing it, lets say I have a role "Verified", this is how I tried to code the embed:

```
.addFields(
{name: "All roles", value: `@Verified means you have accepted the rules\n @Moderator means...`}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to put the User object / GuildMember object and/or the Role object inside the embed and it will get mentioned.

---

```js
const Moderator = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Moderator");
Embed.addField("All Roles", `This is the ${Moderator ? `${Moderator}` : "role not found"} role.`);
```

Note: The following properties of [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/RichEmbed) (Discord JS v11) and [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageEmbed) (Discord JS v12) do not support mentions:

- Author
- Title
- Field Name
- Footer

Comment: Ty, I will approve it when you ensure me it's the only method mentioning a role, then I will unfortunately have to accept those extra line of codes, hoped there would be something around. What about mentioning channels, should be almost the same right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same with channels. There is a way around, but you'll need the role ID. Use `<@&RoleID>` for roles; `<@UserID>` for users; `<#ChannelID>` for channels.

Comment: is there a way to do it with emotes?

Comment: For normal emojis: `<:emojiname:emojiID>`. For animated emojis: `<a:emojiname:emojiID>`.